# mongodb equivalent of sql select 'longfield' as 'a'

Tags: mongodb

Judging by reading through MongoDB documentation, there is no equivalent of sql-like statement

```
SELECT 'field1' as 'a', 'field2' as 'b' ....
```

but because I am in need of such feature, I hope that I missed something.

What is the common practice for dealing with this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common approach is to make a mapping layer in your application to take in a set of fields and then map them to what your application needs.

You are correct that there is not `AS` projection built into MongoDB at all.

I believe you could accomplish this with the aggregation however:

- I don't see why
- It will be heavier and slower than just doing it in the app.

So yea, I would stick to writing a mapping class in the app.

Comment: I agree. I couldn't think of a use-case where you MUST rename fields on the database layer and not on the application layer. On SQL it makes sense, because it has a lot of abilities for transforming the result set (aggregation functions, nonexisting fields calculated from existing ones, joins between tables with column name collisions etc.). But MongoDB leaves all that to the application.