# MongoDB similar to SQL "AS"

Tags: mongodb

How does one rename the columns on a query to mongodb?

This should not permanently alter the columns for future queries or in the database (non-persistent) but rather just for the query

The functionality that I am looking for is similar to SQL's 'AS' as used in `SELECT col1 AS a, col2 as b, col1 as c FROM table`

I am aware that this can be rather trivially processed by the application but was just curious as to how this is implemented in mongodb

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418336/mongodb-equivalent-of-sql-select-longfield-as-a/13419541#13419541

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) can achieve a similar functionality:

```
db.table.aggregate({ $project: { a: '$col1', b: '$col2', c: '$col3' }})
```

It is also possible to filter on a certain conditions by adding a $match in the pipeline:

```
db.table.aggregate(
  { $match: {'col1': 'value'} },
  { $project: { a: '$col1', b: '$col2', c: '$col3' }}
)
```

That said, as the aggregation framework has some [limitations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/#limitations), processing this in the application should be a better choice.

Comment: Ah ok thanks :) I am doing it on the application layer right now but just wanted to know if it was possible on the db level

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible because when retrieving the results the mongo driver maps them to a existing class. if you change the name of the fields the mapping won't be possible